# Switch changes its behaviour when there are more than 5 items in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, sqlite, android-room

I have recyclerView showing list of items from database. In every item there is a switch showing value `true` or `false` depending on database value.
If you change switch state (e.g turn it on/off) it will update value in database with current boolean. What is the problem, that it works well when there are up to 5 items in RecyclerView. If there are more than 5 items Switches of all items change its state to on/randomly and updating the row in database. When I tested by showing just Toast with current state it all worked fine.
I tested on 2 databases with same result: both `sqlite3` with ContentProviders and now I migrated to Room with LiveData.

This is how I set `onCheckedChanged` in my adapter:

```
  @NonNull
    @Override
    public AlarmViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_item, parent, false);
        return new AlarmViewHolder(view);
    }



    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AlarmViewHolder holder, int position) {
       //get data for current adapter position
            Alarms currentData = mAlarms.get(position);
//check if alarm is valid and then set this value to the switch
            holder.isAlarmActiveSwitch.setChecked(currentData.isValid());
      new validationUpdater().switchChangedListener
                    (holder.isAlarmActiveSwitch,
                    context, currentData.get_id());`  
    }
```

I create instance of `validationUpdater()` class and call the method `switchChangedListener`, pass `holder.isAlarmActiveSwitch` as Switch, `context` and `id` of row in Database.

`switchChangedListener()` method:

```
public void switchChangedListener(@NotNull final Switch switchActive, @NotNull final Context context, final long id) {
        switchActive.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton compoundButton, final boolean b) {
                AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AlarmDatabase db = AlarmDatabase.getInstance(context);
                        AlarmsDao dao = db.alarmsDao();
                        dao.updateAlarm(id, b);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

and @Query from Dao:

```
@Query("UPDATE alarm_table SET valid = :valid WHERE _id = :id") 
void updateAlarm(final long id, final boolean valid);
```

Could anyone explain me why this doesn't work as supposed only **after** more than 5 items are displayed?

Comment: i'm not sure, but since you are using RecyclerView, i guess you are doing wrong with OnCheckChangeListener. maybe you are setting OnCheckChangeListener at onCreateViewHolder and when ViewHolder has been reused, it uses previous data to update database.

Comment: @yeonseok.seo I've updated my adapter code. I'm setting onCheckChangeListener inside `onBindViewHolder` method

Comment: hope this resolve after overrieding the getItemViewType method 
    @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

Comment: @ZahoorSaleem please post your comment as the answer, it did work for me. Also could you provide me any logical explanation how it worked? I read documentation for this method, it is clear for me but I don't understand why it changed behaviour of Switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is row item duplication in recycler view overried the getItemViewType method, hope this works for you.

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```